# Visual studio 2013 pro peek definition hangs

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Any idea why Visual Studio peek definition will not work for any project or solution? I have a web, WP and a couple other ones. I can click on a class or method or property and click alt+F12 or right click and select peek definition. The peek window pops up with a progress bar like it is working but just hangs there. Nothing ever shows up in the peek window. Half the time I get this and half the time VS just crashes on me when I try and launch it. I have done a VS repair but that changed nothing.

Comment: it's hard to say without error messages or any other helpful debugging info. No doubt it should work fine...It sounds like VS installation might have been corrupted. I'd do a fresh uninstall and reinstall. Sorry couldn't be of more help :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I uninstalled a couple dev prod tools and then did another repair and this time it fixed the issue. Peek pops up right away. So something was getting in the way.

Comment: I am having the same issue.  Can you say which tools you removed?

Comment: I removed DevExpress CodeRush and then did a repair. This also fixed the issue I was having exporting tasks lists from TFS to excel.